# I can't use gpu in Colab pro

Tags: gpu, google-colaboratory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw0CZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYEK9.png)

I am using colab pro. About 4 months ago, I experienced slow learning of the tensorflow model. The learning speed is so slow, and as a result of checking it myself today, I was able to confirm that the gpu was detected normally, but the GPU POWER was off. The volatile GPU Util is also allocated as 0 , but it looks like the GPU is not being utilized for training. When I looked for the cause, there was a saying that the data I/O bottleneck was, so I also modified the DATALOADER, and when I ran the same code and dataset in a different COLAB account, I was able to see that the GPU allocation worked well and the time was also shortened. If there is a problem with the os settings or if there is something I need to fix, please let me know. have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the problem was simply a path problem. As we've gotten feedback before, it seems like there's been a bottleneck in loading images through folders.
It was solved by specifying the path of the dataset as content/ .